# Interpretability of Regression Categorical Variable Coefficients with Insignificant Intercept

Tags: r, regression, logistic, categorical-data

I am running a logistic regression on two categorical predictors: genre (0, 1) and company (1, 2, 3). The results are below.

```
                   Estimate  Std. Error  z value    Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)        -0.3449   0.2200      -1.568     0.11693    
company2           1.0565    0.3992      2.647      0.00813 ** 
company3           1.3980    0.3381      4.135      0.000035487 ***
genre1             -2.0045   0.3915      -5.120     0.000000306 ***
```

If the intercept (standing in for company1 and genre0) is not significant, does that affect the interpretability of my other results? I am interested in deriving the probability of y for each combination of company and genre using the inverse logit function, as well as how the probabilities compare across the levels of each predictor.

Comment: What do you mean by  “interpretabiliry” here?

Comment: @Tim Sorry, when I say interpretability, I mean in terms of using the coefficient estimates to understand the relationship between each predictor and the probability. For example, would there be any issues with me inferring that we see a 21% probability for those in company2 and genre1 using `invlogit(-0.3449 + 1.0565 - 2.0045)`? Should I avoid making claims, such as “company3 has a higher probability compared to company1” since company1 is not a significant predictor?

Comment: When interpreting the results you simply need to consider the uncertainty, which is high in the case of the nonsignificant parameters.